# Force in an isolated capacitor when a dielectric slab is introduced

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

my question is about capacitance:
a dielectric slab is inserted between the plates of an isolated capacitor. The force between the plates will remain unchanged. how? 
I mean the knowledge I had gained is that 
                  $$E=F/q$$
since a dielectric slab is being introduced in an isolated capacitor therefore 
                 $$ E(new)=E(old)/K$$
               where $K =$ dielectic constant of slab 
         then $$F(new)=F(old)/K $$
[as $F=Eq$] please correct me

Comment: What do you mean by an isolated capacitor?

Comment: By isolated they mean the capacitor is not connected to any battery source, and its the only thing that exist in space, so anything else don't affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the dielectric is inserted in between the plates of an isolated capacitor, the electric field E **inside the dielectric** decrease k times. Outside the dielectric, at the location where plates are situated, electric field is same as before, hence the force between them don't change.

Even if you fill the space in between the plates completely with a dielectric, one can imagine the plates to be having some thickness, and so at any interior point of one plate there is no dielectric.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir But even the F is inversely proportional to epsinlon ...if there is change in the the value of epsinlon the F should also get affected .....also if the medium between the plates is totally filled with the dielectric then how is there any space for original electric field ?

Comment: Outside dielectric, epsilon don't change.